# Java Variable socpe :Accessing Variable value issue

Tags: java, variables, scope

hello i am beginner and  this question could be stupid  dont mind please guide me , 
I am doing Small code in where i read a file  and  text is stored in a String like this .

```
ReadFile()
{
   String s;
   String end="$";

   BufferedReader br= new  BufferedReader(newFileReader("c:\\users\\sikander\\desktop\\hi.txt"));
   while((s=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        s=s+end;

    } 

}
```

Now what i want is to access the value of  `s`   in another method but when i acccess it does not get the updated value ,  Please help me for this simple problem

Comment: You have to make `s` an instance variable. As of now, it is local to the constructor so it's not going to visible from the method.

Comment: use `StringBuffer` for appending strings.

Comment: @BheshGurung  still output is null, not an error it prints "null" means not reading file contents from String

Comment: @SikanderNawaz you can try solution which I gave in answer..

Comment: You need an extra string variable to hold the line read, which you will append to `s`. As of now, the at the end of the while loop `s` will be null.

Comment: @BheshGurung Thanks a log sir  its fine , i was   talking and printing value from save variable that i changed  as you told.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables cannot be accessed by any other method, instead you could

```
return s;
```

form a method. Change your method to:

```
public String ReadFile() {}
```

And in another string variable, you can do like this.

```
String j = ReadFile();
```

Comment: i did  make it instance level String s ; but  still that  prints " null" instead of  String data

Comment: its solve , did this     "You need an extra string variable to hold the line read, which you will append to s. As of now, the at the end of the while loop s will be null. – Bhesh Gurung "  Thanks a lot answr 1+ for your reply thansk